# URI to image on activity started blank

Tags: java, android, kotlin

API 30

This is going to all sound very scrambled, because I've very conf

The following works perfectly fine, it loads the image into 'imCardImage' widget without problem.

```
val getContentCardImage = registerForActivityResult(ActivityResultContracts.GetContent())  { uri: Uri? ->
imCardImage.setImageURI(uri)    // Handle the returned Uri
cImageCardStr = uri.toString()
Log.d("EditCards","URI = "+uri.toString())
Log.d("EditCards","(mydecklist) URI = "+mydecklist[cCardPosition].c_image)
```

}

The problem appears when, I exit the app and restart it/go to another activity within the same application, all the images are gone it's as if I had temporary permission while the activity was active, in the area where you can select images and revoked the instant that activity is terminated, and yet I've requested permission from the use and been granted it.

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
```

I did get this error; Permission Denial: opening provider com.android.providers.media.MediaDocumentsProvider but for some odd reason it's stopped happening for some unknown reason.

```
    override fun onBindViewHolder( holder: ViewHolder, position: Int ) {

    holder.cardTitle.text = "[$position] "+mydecklist[position].c_title
    holder.cardMessage.text = mydecklist[position].c_message
    holder.cardImage.setImageURI(mydecklist[position].c_image.toUri())
}
```

The above is supposed to load the image from mydecklist[#].c_image in to a RecycleView / CardView, but is blank when starting the app.

```
14727-14727/com.example.cardgamexxx E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
Process: com.example.cardgamexxx, PID: 14727
java.lang.SecurityException: Permission Denial: opening provider com.android.providers.media.MediaDocumentsProvider from ProcessRecord{bc01e1c 14727:com.example.cardgamexxx/u0a734} (pid=14727, uid=10734) requires that you obtain access using ACTION_OPEN_DOCUMENT or related APIs
```

-- error is back, thanks to "mehul bisht" no actually I did want that back :) see my reply to your comment.

```
        // Permissions
    permissionsLauncher = registerForActivityResult(ActivityResultContracts.RequestMultiplePermissions()) { permissions ->
        readPermissionGranted = permissions[Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE] ?: readPermissionGranted
    }
    requestPermissions()
```

Permission already requested, if there is some other permission I should be asking for I'd love to know.

**EDIT 2**

Pretty sure I might have an idea, I might be entirely wrong though!

```
registerForActivityResult()...
```

Above when the user selects the image the image is resolved? uri is valid? I have permission at this point? no idea why that works but it works.

```
holder.cardImage.setImageURI(mydecklist[position].c_image.toUri())
```

That's the deploy line that sends the image to the cardImage widget, but is in a mutable list as a type string which I am converting to a Uri. *I suppose that is okay.* however it doesn't work when loading the application from a restart or just switching to another activity in the same application and back again, so either I need to resolve the uri so that it's valid again or takepermission to have access to it always.

NB: it would be better if I had my own folder that users could drop files in that I had total access to but I don't know how to do that so, I have to go the overly convoluted obtuse route.

Comment: did you check inside your `onBindViewHolder` if the `URI` is non null?

Comment: @mehulbisht no the URI wasn't null, "content://com.android.providers.media.documents/document/image%3A17233content://com.android.providers.media.documents/document/image%3A17233" 

but it did remind me to fix it so it was trying to use a URI, so I could crash better! LOL

Comment: it seems you need to request permission, not only in Manifest, you have to request permission in code. From android 5 or above, some important permission should be given from user.

Comment: @RollandCostomarob permission already requested and given, as per edit above, not the complete code, I didn't feel it was necessary just prof of due diligence.

Comment: you can check if it has such permission in Setting->Apps->permission. on your phone

Comment: And it does have permission... :)